# Where is linux process descriptor stored and what can access it?

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, linux-kernel, x86

I read that the process descriptor in Linux (on x86) is stored in the kernel data segment but at an address below PAGE_OFFSET (i.e. in user address space). Since the kernel data segment and user data segments both cover the full 4GB address space, then presumably it would be possible to access the process descriptor through the user data segment, if its address was known to user code. Is this correct, and if so, is it not a security hole?

A related question: there was an assertion that the linear address of the process descriptor can serve as a unique process ID. However, as linear addresses get translated using the page table, and the page table is different for every process for addresses below PAGE_OFFSET, then couldn't two processes store their process descriptors at the same linear address?

Comment: Where did you read that? I don't see anythinig about the process descriptor being in user space in http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=368650

Comment: Don't see anything like that here either: http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS01/OS/Lectures/Lecture05.pdf

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an invalid premise.  Kind of like the "typo" or "can't reproduce" close-reason.  Maybe edit it to just ask where the `task_struct` lives so it matches the answer?

Comment: My source is this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Daniel-Plerre/dp/0596005652) - or more specifically the diagram which is reproduced verbatim in the pdf that @Barmar links above, on slide 6. The process descriptor is shown as being at address 0x015fa000, which is below PAGE_OFFSET on x86. The book also says: "Since processes are dynamic entities, process descriptors are are stored in dynamic memory rather than the memory area permanently assigned to the kernel". It's unclear what they mean...

Comment: @PeterCordes: I changed the subject.

Answer (score 4):

In linux, the "process descriptor" is `struct task_struct` [and some others]. These are stored in *kernel* address space [above `PAGE_OFFSET`] and *not* in userspace.

This is more relevant to 32 bit kernels where `PAGE_OFFSET` is set to 0xc0000000.

In a 32 bit kernel, a user process virtual address space was limited to `PAGE_OFFSET`

64 bit kernels are somewhat different and the limit doesn't matter as much. `PAGE_OFFSET` is 0xffff880000000000

Also, the kernel has a single address space mapping of its own.

Each process/thread has its own virtual address space, that, barring shared memory for .so libraries and shared memory for threads is unique. It does *not* map to anything in kernel address space.

Even with [if there were] a common address space mapping the kernel pages are read/write protected from the user process.

---

> A related question:

This is really two questions

> there was an assertion that the linear address of the process descriptor can serve as a unique process ID.

No. This can *not* be done for a few reasons.

Only the kernel has access to (i.e. "knows") the `task_struct` address.

Secondly, if a process terminates, it is a zombie until the parent process "reaps" it via `wait`. The kernel must remember which processes are zombies (i.e. their `pids` will *not* be reused for a new process) until the parent reaps them.

The `task_struct` is rather large, though. So, when a process enters zombie, the kernel grabs a *small* portion of the `task_struct` data (e.g. `pid` and `status`) and saves them in a "zombie" struct. The kernel can then reuse the `task_struct` [using a *different* pid] almost immediately.

For example, while a process with pid 37 may have had a task struct at address (e.g.) 0x1000 while it was running, after termination, but before reap, pid 37 has *no* task struct address and the task struct at 0x1000 could already be assigned to pid 23727

> However, as linear addresses get translated using the page table, and the page table is different for every process for addresses below PAGE_OFFSET, then couldn't two processes store their process descriptors at the same linear address?

Once again, no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I presume you're right, but could you review my comment above and help clarify the confusion? Secondly, is there any good recent book on the kernel that would cover e.g. the x86-64 memory management? The only book I found is too old: [book from 2005](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Daniel-Plerre/dp/0596005652).